# Java WebCam Streaming over TCP Socket, redirecting image sequences to client-recipient

Tags: java, sockets, tcp, webcam

Thank you in advance for your time and effort!
Currently, I am building an instant messaging application and have been including Webcam streaming functionality via the Sarxos Webcam API from Github. 
The implementation of my application is that another thread on the OS of the machine running the server app opens whenever a client is accepted, and clients are stored in a MySql Database. I have not yet learned IO multiplexing thus am sticking with this implementation for the time-being.

Regarding the WebCam streaming, I am able to send the Images from the client app to the server app, and the server application is receiving the sequence of images and rendering a video just fine and without lag.

However, my trouble is REDIRECTING these sequences of images (videos) from the server to the specified client for which the client initiating the stream wishes to video chat with.

I have tried too many implementations to list, but here is my current code:

CLIENT APPLICATION:

```
    Thread t1 = new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (true) {
                BufferedImage frame = webCam.getImage();
                int frameWidth = frame.getWidth();
                int frameHeight = frame.getHeight();

                try {
                    videoOutputStream.writeInt(frameWidth);
                    videoOutputStream.writeInt(frameHeight);

                    int[] pixelData = new int[frameWidth * frameHeight];
                    frame.getRGB(0, 0, frameWidth, frameHeight, pixelData, 0, frameWidth);
                    for (int i = 0; i < pixelData.length; i++) {
                        videoOutputStream.writeInt(pixelData[i]);
                    }
                     Thread.sleep(20);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    };
    t1.start();
```

SERVER APPLICATION:

```
      BufferedImage frame; 

        while (true) {

    //Client who is SENDING images via webcam is using the "videoInputStream" object 
    //Client who is RECEIVING these images is using the "recipientVideoOutputStream" object 

DataOutputStream recipientVideoOutputStream = c.getVideoOutputStream(); 
                int frameWidth = videoInputStream.readInt(); 
                int frameHeight = videoInputStream.readInt();

                frame = new BufferedImage(frameWidth, frameHeight, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);

                recipientVideoOutputStream.writeInt(frameWidth);
                recipientVideoOutputStream.writeInt(frameHeight);

                int[] pixelData = new int[frameWidth * frameHeight];
                for (int i = 0; i < pixelData.length; i++) {
                    pixelData[i] = videoInputStream.readInt();
                }

                for (int i = 0; i < pixelData.length; i++) {
                    recipientVideoOutputStream.writeInt(pixelData[i]); //This is where we write/re-direct the images as bytes to the receiving client
                }
            }
```

And, now, the code for the client application when it is RECEIVING a video feed, which was sent client-server, and server is now redirecting the images to specified client recipient:

```
            Thread t1 = new Thread() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    int frameWidth;
                    int frameHeight;
                    int[] pixelData;
                    BufferedImage frame;
                    Image imagefx;

                    while (true) {

                        try {
                            frameWidth = videoInputStream.readInt();
                            frameHeight = videoInputStream.readInt();
                            pixelData = new int[frameWidth * frameHeight];

                            for (int i = 0; i < pixelData.length; i++) {
                                pixelData[i] = videoInputStream.readInt();
                                System.out.println("CLIENT READING PIXEL DATA " + pixelData[i]);
                            }

                            frame = new BufferedImage(frameWidth, frameHeight, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
                            frame.setRGB(0, 0, frameWidth, frameHeight, pixelData, 0, frameWidth);

                            imagefx = SwingFXUtils.toFXImage(frame, null);
                            System.out.println("CLIENT GOT IMAGE " + imagefx);
                            videoStreamStage.updateImage(imagefx); //Sets the image for the client's stage showing the streamed video, this is within a Platform.runLater()
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
            };
```

Currently, the receiving client see's about 1 frame before crashing with a NegativeArraySizeException, sometimes alongside a memory heap exception. 
I can pass the images rendering a video from client-server without issue, but redirecting the video feed to another client has eaten my entire weekend and sadly without success.

(EDIT): The NegativeArraySizeException is thrown while executing the following line within the client application, (the client which is RECEIVING the streamed images):

```
pixelData = new int[frameWidth * frameHeight];
```

How am I to re-direct these images to the specified client recipient and, is it even do-able with my implementation as it stands?

Thank you again for your time!

Comment: Just a comment, sending uncompressed RGB as a "video stream" is a bad idea, even over a local network, and you're bound to run into lots of issues the more clients your application tries to cater for. While you might not see any lag now, wait until you stream higher resolutions/bitrates or when there's network congestion. As a starting point it could be helpful to read up on technologies such as WebRTC, take a look at video codecs (e.g. x264, VP8, VP9, etc) and look at transport protocols such as RTP, RTCP, RTSP, SIP, etc.

Comment: I don't know about any of that, only standard TCP socket transferring :( Anything to point me in a single direction to help me learn? Looking up everything mentioned is overwhelming and doesn't render a big picture for me

Comment: In a nutshell, you want to compress your video using some codec (H264, VP8, etc) to *vastly* reduce the number of bits sent over the network, on the other side you decode the video and "restore" the "original" frame, usually with some minor loss of quality (depending on your encoder settings). As for the transport over a network, various standards such as RTP (https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3550) exist that specify how encoded video is sent over the Internet (usually UDP) but this depends on the application requirements. UDP is usually needed for real-time time media (think conversational).

Comment: Trying trying trying and trying.. these external codecs are really complicated lol...